# XmlDocument.Save() inserts empty square brackets in doctype declaration

Tags: c#, xml

Everytime I call the method on

```
XmlDocument.Save(fooFilepath);
```

it inserts two square brackets at the end of the DOCTYPE tag e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ARCXML SYSTEM "G:\ArcIMS\DTD\arcxml.dtd"[]>
```

Does anyone know why this might happen?  I obviously don't want this to happen.

Comment: The square brackets are the place where internal subset declarations are placed. If you don't have such declarations, the brackets are empty and may be omitted. But it's not wrong to have empty brackets. Any standards-conforming XML parser should be able to deal with the generated doctype declaration, so the only issue you have is an aesthetic one.

Comment: After checking out the `XmlWriter.WriteDocType()` implementations, I'm puzzled why a new `XDocumentType` with `internalSubset` set to `null` outputs the empty squary brackets.In my case, I'm writing to Response.Output. Before calling `Save()`, I confirmed that `doc.DocumentType.InternalSubset` is null. All implementations seem to skip outputting `[]` but at runtime it's written to the XML by something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is [a normal (and optional) part of a DOCTYPE declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration).

```
<!DOCTYPE rootname SYSTEM url [DTD]>
```

Where *DTD* contains any internal subset declarations to your document.

Comment: right! - I had no idea, it just looked odd but if it's valid, well, its all good. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, it is valid xml syntax, but some parsers can't handle it.

Answer (score 5):

The underlying reader used by `XmlDocument` (which uses `XmlTextReader`) does not distinguish between a document with an empty internal subset and one with no internal subset specified, so it will return `InternalSubset == ""` for both cases.

Then when `XmlDocument.Save()` is called, it sees an empty string for `InternalSubset` and dutifully writes an empty internal subset: `[]`.

Unfortunately, `XmlDocument.DocumentType.InternalSubset` is readonly, so you cannot set it to null. You can either do:

1. Use the lower level `XmlTextWriter.WriteDocType()` to have more control.
2. Use `XDocument`, where you can set `XDocument.DocumentType.InternalSubset = null`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was also including blank spaces all around the xml...
What worked in my case at the end is saving the document using XDocument instead of XmlDocument:

```cs
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

// Assuming you already have an XmlDocument named 'xmlDoc'
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
// ... Code to load/manipulate the XmlDocument ...

// Convert the XmlDocument into an XmlReader
using (XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc))
{
    // Create the XDocument from the XmlReader
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);

    // Modify the InternalSubset:
    if (xDoc.DocumentType != null)
    {
        xDoc.DocumentType.InternalSubset = null;
    }

    // Save the XDocument
    xDoc.Save("yourFilePath.xml");
}
```